# Getting index of a std::vector<std::string>::iterator

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl, iterator

So that's what I have tried so far:

```
class menu_item
{
  private:

    // ....

    std::vector<std::string> options_;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator current_;

  public:
    menu_item(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> options)
        : name_(name), options_(options)
    {
        current_ = begin(options_);
    }

    // ....

    const int curr_opt_id()
    {
        return current_ - begin(options_);
    }
};
```

But `curr_opt_id()` returns `-24`. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you using your `menu_item` class? Are you adding elements to `options_` after initialization?

Comment: Like that: http://pastebin.com/cjVKjxFW

Comment: That does not answer my question though

Comment: `menu_item`s are added to a `std::vector<shared_ptr<menu_item>>` in my `list_menu` class. And no, I'm not adding any elements to options_ after initialization.

Comment: Then you should prepare an [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org). I cannot reproduce the behavior based on the code you provided

Comment: My `list_menu` class invalidated the iterators. Thanks for all answers, problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add to a vector, there's a chance that the internal storage will be reallocated which will invalidate all existing iterators. Doing arithmetic on an invalid iterator isn't going to end well.

See [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score 2):

Iterators of a vector get invalidated upon reallocation, which happens when the current capacity is not sufficient to hold the actual content plus a newly added element.

What is most likely happening here is that the `current_` iterator, which is initialized at construction time, gets invalidated by subsequent insertions into `options_`, which gives you undefined behavior when evaluating the expression:

```
current_ - begin(options_)
```